# How to handle 'NULL' values in SparkSQL?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

My Hive table had some `NULL` values which I needed to filter out. But when I ran queries like `"x IS NOT NULL"`, `"x != NULL"`, `"x <> NULL"`, none of them worked.
After a bit of searching I found out that I have to tell the Hive parser to treat the `NULL` values as specified by the property `serialization.null.format`.

I need to know where I can set this.

Can I do this by calling the `setConf` function on the `Hive Context` when I start `SparkSQL`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your Spark SQL `IF isnull` case by case.